# The Galactic Plane

Tags: astrophysics

I'm guessing this isn't a great physics question, but I just can't find an answer with Google.
If the galactic plane is perfectly horizontal at what angle and rotation will the ecliptic plane of our Solar System be?

Comment: Are you asking for the angle of inclination of the solar system's ecliptic plane with respect to the galactic plane?

Comment: @David: I think so. I think he's also asking for the precession speed of our SSEP with respect to the galaxy's reference frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Galactic Plane and Solar Orienation]
[image: Galactic Coordinates and Earth]

The answer seems to near [60 degrees](http://cs.astronomy.com/asycs/forums/p/31176/368880.aspx). Additional description [here](http://stars.astro.illinois.edu/celsph.html)

I have found this mathematica description of the ecliptic plane relative to the galactic plane.

[Wolfram.com](http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/astronomy/GalacticCoordinates.html)

Comment: That first image is simply amazing.

Comment: @space_cadet Well the 1st image certainly isn't real (as in to scale)

Comment: @Jonathan -AWww, and I thought it was a real photograph ;)